# How do I complete numerous jobs with a few threads giving each the same timeout to complete?

Tags: java, future, executorservice, executor

An idea I am trying to implement is the following.

1. I have 1000 urls to download data from to use it for post processing (say, calculating some statistics).
   I don't really need all of the downloads to finish successfully, but as many as possible.
2. I assume that some of the locations might be unavailable, either responding nothing valuable (e.g., HTTP 503) or taking more that TO=10 seconds of time to process a request.
3. I have T=5 threads to process the urls in parallel, giving the equal timeout TO to each.
4. As soon as one completes (what I expect to happen far earlier that TO exceeds) I aggregate some statistics (what is a very fast operation) and start the next download (if any).

The solution I have come up so far with is

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(T);

ExecutorCompletionService<MyResult> completionService = new ExecutorCompletionService<>(executorService);
urls.forEach(url -> {
    Callable<MyResult> callable = () -> new MyResult(url);
    completionService.submit(callable);
}); 

for (int i = 0; i < urls.size(); i++) {
    Future<MyResult> resultFuture = completionService.poll(TO, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    if (resultFuture == null)
        continue;
    MyResult myResult = resultFuture.get();
    myAggregate(myResult.getRate());
}
```

It looks like somewhat I am trying to achieve. But it for instance neither gives every download the same timeout nor cancels the Futures properly. So, what is the correct solution?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the invokeAll-Method, you simply put your Callables in a List and then call invokeAll() on your ExecutorService giving it a timeout as second and third argument.

```
executorService.invokeAll(callableList, 20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Comment: as I mentioned above, my intention is to give the same timeout to each of the futures, while the `invokeAll` awaits exactly 20 seconds, no matter how large `callableList` is.